# express.js + socket.io - how to initialize session on server from client app

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I have to create 2 apps. One app is a server using express.js and socket.io. Second app is a simple client (static html+js file) and must not be served from server express.js instance. The cookie `express.sid` witch is used to establish session is created only when express.js route is accessed.

My problem occurs when I'm connecting from client (ie. http://client.addr) to server (ie. http://server.addr:0000) using socket.io - I can't establish express.js session because I didn't accessed the server route and I don't have `express.sid` session cookie.

I ended up with client trying to send AJAX call to server `/set-session-cookie` route in hope I can identify session, send back cookie with encrypted `sessionID` and than start socket.io connection hooking in to session that was created in previous call but no cookie is sent back after AJAX call.

Server route:

```
app.all('/set-sesion-cookie', function(req, res){
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    res.cookie('express.sid2', req.sessionID, {signed: true});
    res.send(200);
});
```

Client call:

```
$.post('http://127.0.0.1:3000/set-sesion-cookie');
```

Second thought was to send back only string containing encrypted session id and create cookie using JS but I can't find out what the encryption algorithm is for `res.cookie('express.sid2', req.sessionID, {signed: true});` to do it manually.

Is this approach valid? If there is another way to achieve this please let me know. TIA.

Comment: you should try authenticating socket.io handshake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO session cookies should be HTTP-Only for security reasons.
This means there is no scripting support for this cookie.

You can avoid the [Same-Origin-Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) problem by serving static files w/ nginx and reverse [proxy node.js app behind nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule). This way all comes from one server and you don't have problems sharing a cookie/session-id.

AFAIK Apache httpd is not able to proxy WebSocket calls.

Another possible workaround instead of nginx might be [HAProxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/).